# HTML5 event for `onselectionchange`

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a standard cross-browser HTML5 event which corresponds to IE legacy [onselectionchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (so it is fired when the current selection changes)?

**EDITED**, I'm looking to track [Selection object](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#selections) changes.

Comment: What's wrong with `onchange`?

Comment: I might be wrong, but doesn't `onchange` get fired when the content of the element is changed? I'm after the cursor position changes, not the content changes.

Comment: actually onchange is fired when content losses focus.

Comment: you want event when selection of text is changed?

Comment: @DeepSharma, yes, when `document.getSelection().anchorNode` or `document.getSelection().anchorOffset` are changing. I can use timer to track that asynchronously with any HTML5 browser, and I can use [onselectionchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to track that synchronously with IE9/10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `onchange`

I recommend using jQuery to avoid these cross browser issues, but that does not mean you should skip testing. [see here](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Look at **[Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/)** `window.getSelection = rangy.getSelection`

it might work...

```
/* 
IE 8 getSelection() missing object and properties simple hack
*/
if (window.getSelection == undefined) {                /* IE? */
    var wgS = setInterval(function(){                  /* wait for Rangy */
        if (rangy.initialized) {
            window.getSelection = rangy.getSelection;  /* do the stuff */
            clearTimeout(wgS);                         /* exit */
        }
     }, 10);
}
```

Source : Web

Comment: Sorry, `onchange` doesn't work for what I've asked. Functionally, `onchange` and `onselectionchange` are different even in IE.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but I only asked if there's an *existing* standard HTML5 event like `onselectionchange` of IE. I'll accept your answer if there is no standard event like that, but I'd like to wait a bit first. I'm very surprised there's a standard for `Selection` DOM API, but no standard event to track selection changes.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: No, I'm going to use `onselectionchange` with IE and emulate it under other browsers. I might indeed use Rangy if it supports HTML5 Selection API. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Never too late :

```
// IE
myEditableElement.onselectionchange = onSelectionChange;
// work on chrome, untested on firefox
myEditableElement.addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
  document.addEventListener('selectionchange', onSelectionChange);
});
myEditableElement.addEventListener('focusout', function (event) {
  document.removeEventListener('selectionchange', onSelectionChange);
});

// Event
function onSelectionChange (event) {
  // todo
}
```

Comment: `document.addEventListener('selectionchange', onSelectionChange)` Tested and works to get the selection on Chrome 102. Never too late!

Answer (score 2):

you can find the cursor position on the keyup event handler. eg.

```js
function getCursorPos(evt){
   if(window.getSelection){
  var sel=document.getSelection();
  if(sel.rangeCount==0){return;}
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  var p=range.startOffset;
 }else{
  var sel=document.selection;
  if(sel){
  var range=sel.createRange();
  var p=range.offsetLeft;}
 }

  document.getElementById('myoutposition').innerHTML=p;
  
  }

if(addEventListener){
  document.getElementById('myeditbox').addEventlistener('keyup',getCursorPos,false);
  }
else{
  document.getElementById('myeditbox').attachEvent('onkeyup',getCursorPos);}
```

```html
<textarea id="myeditbox" style="width:100%;height:100px;"></textarea><br/>
the current cursor position is&nbsp;<output id="myoutposition">0</output>
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard is `onchange`:

```
<select id="myName" onchange="myMethod(this)">
...
</select>
```

This can also be used for textboxes etc.

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp.

Comment: Does `onchange` get fired when I simply move the caret inside `<textarea>`?  `onselectionchange` does, that's actually what I'm after.

Comment: No, `onchange` gets triggered after you have made a change. So in the `textarea` it will only fire after the user leaves the field (by submitting the form or by typing TAB or...). AFAIK there is no HTML5 equivalent of what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to track it using timer then.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the onChange attribute.

```
<input type='text' onChange='alert(this.value)'>
```

The onchange event occurs when the value of an element has been changed.

For radiobuttons and checkboxes, the onchange event occurs when the checked state has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange events, it worked perfectly fine with my multi-select.

`<select onchange="myFunction()" multiple>`.

Initially, I had problems because I was trying to use the multi-select created using bootstrap classes with the **onblur event** i.e `<select onblur="myFunction()" multiple>` event. This didn’t work since my multi-select was created using **div** (which uses bootstrap classes) as a result I could not **focusin** or **focusout** and that caused the **onblur** not to trigger.

On a plain html select the **onblur** works just fine. So, you can try it as well.